Mapping object by address
I am interested to use JSON for storing the initial parameters for an application written in C++. Currently I am testing the nlohmann/json library for read/write data from/to JSON files.
I have the following class structure:
class Layer {
public:
    std::string name;
    LayerType type;
    ...
};

class Network {
public:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Layer> layers;
    ...
};

and the serialize/deserialize methods are here:
void to_json(json& j, const Layer& layer) {
    j = json{
            {"name", layer.name},
            {"type", layer.type}
    };
}
void from_json(const json& j, Layer& layer) {
    j.at("name").get_to(layer.name);
    j.at("type").get_to(layer.type);
}

void to_json(json& j, const Network& network) {
    j = json{
        {"name", network.name},
        {"layers", network.layers}
    };
}
void from_json(const json& j, Network& network) {
    j.at("name").get_to(network.name);
    j.at("layers").get_to(network.layers);
}

So, up to here, these classes are fine and can be used to read and write from and to JSON.
And now comes the question. What if I decide to use addresses of layers in the Network class?
class Network {
public:
    std::vector<Layer*> layers;
    ...
};

How should I rewrite the serialize/deserialize methods? Where can I find a similar example?
SK


How should I rewrite the serialize/deserialize methods?

YES
Semantically it doesn't make sense to store C++ objects addresses in your json, because you are interested in your structures content, not in their internal representation in the memory.
You can e.g. change your Network serializer to transform vector of pointers to Layer to array of json objects representing Layer:
void to_json(nlohmann::json& j, const Network& network) {
    j["name"] = network.name;
    j["layers"] = nlohmann::json::array({});
    for (auto* lPtr : network.layers) {
        j["layers"].push_back(*lPtr);
    }
}

Then you also need to adjust your from_json accordingly.
